# Excel - Error 400 for SaveAs operation

Tags: excel, vba, macos, runtime-error, save-as

So I am new to Excel VBA stuff and I have a problem here...

My code is as follows..

```
Sub Export()

Dim FileName As String
Dim Path As String
Path = "~/Desktop"
FileName = Range("B4").Value & ".pdf"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Path & FileName
End Sub
```

and what I am trying to do is to get a value from the string `B4` (the filename) and try to export the file in `.pdf` format. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Please help!

Comment: here's a pro tip...record a macro and see the syntax of the saving event.  Change your code to match, then worry about variables.

Comment: You need a `PathSeparator` between the path and filename - i.e. `Path & Application.PathSeparator & FileName`.  But is `"~/Desktop"` a valid path?

Comment: @YowE3K ~/Desktop is a valid path

Comment: @sous2817 I did it but the problem is that later I have a messed up macro and I don't know how insert the string variable as there is no `filename` thing in the macro

Comment: Include into the question the `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs` line that was generated by the macro - it will be easy enough to show how to modify that to use a calculated path/filename.

Comment: @YowE3K `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="/Users/krychevsk16/Desktop/asdasd.pdf", _
        FileFormat:=xlPDF`

Comment: Then you want your statement to be `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=Path & Application.PathSeparator & Filename, FileFormat:=xlPDF`, but it doesn't appear that `~/Desktop` will be the right path - that will be referring to the `~/Desktop` directory within the current directory (which may not be where you are expecting it to be).

Comment: @YowE3K Then I just include the full directory directly from `/Users/`?

Comment: @YowE3K I got more errors now, the "printing" error and again 400 error

Comment: Is this a Mac??

Comment: @YowE3K yes, it is a mac

Comment: OK - forget everything I said about the tilde character - it may have special meaning on a Mac.  (I'll retag your question so that the people who know about Macs might look at it.)

Comment: @YowE3K Sure, I also can't save the file now and this really pisses me off. In the cell with a file name for some reason, I can see ".pdf" which completely makes no sense.